# BankAccount Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying the `toString` to display the account number and the balance but it didn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
public class Account 
{

    double accountBalance;
    double deposit;
    double accountNumber;

    public Account(double initialDeposit) 
    {
    this.accountBalance = initialDeposit;
    this.accountNumber = 5; 

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        this.accountBalance;
        this.accountNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read a tutorial about methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the members...

Comment: public String toString()
{
    return "" + this.accountBalance " " +  this.accountNumber;
}

Comment: "*but it didn't work*" doesn't tell us much. Try to include in your question exact error you are seeing. This way we will be able to focus on that error, and people with similar problem will be able to google your question and potentially answers for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `toString()` method to display a string that represents the object you should not be returning a `String`, you should be printing it out. Also if you want to print it out, toString() could not be the best name available. You can do it as follows:

```
public void display(){
System.out.println("Account balance: "+this.accountBalance + ", Account Number: "+this.accountNumber);
}
```

If instead you want the `toString()` method to return a `String` which represents the object, then you can do this:

```
public String toString(){
return "Account balance: "+this.accountBalance + ", Account Number: "+this.accountNumber;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that it is common/(good?) practice to have the toString() return a string rather than printout itself.

Comment: @tlw11591 It is not only *common/(good?) practice to have the toString() return a string*, it is impossible to change return type of overridden method to `void` if it was previously declared as something else (and `toString` method exists in every class since it was introduced in Object class). In other words, we can't have something like `public void toString(){...}` in Java.

Comment: @Pshemo excellent point! :D I suppose I meant, rather than saying something like 'print(...); return null;'

Comment: Yes guys, you are right. However I found important to make the user notice the importance of the signature rather than its funcionality. Gonna edit the method's name, though. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add @Override to the method and format the balance accordingly.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Balance on account number " + this.accountNumber +" is " + String.format("%1$,.2f", this.accountBalance); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a string from the `toString()` method.

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Account Balance: " accountBalance + " Account Number: " + accountNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to return a string from toString() function.

```
public String toString()
    {
        return this.accountNumber +"=> "+ this.accountBalance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of `toString()` method is to `return` simple (and preferably short) String describing current object. This way later you can make decision if you want to:

- print it on console `System.out.println(account.toString());`
- place it into logs `log.log( Level.FINE, "processing {0}", account.toString());`
- or do something else like sending it somewhere.

That is why `toString()` was declared as

```
public String toString()
//     ^^^^^^ - before name of method we describe type of data which should be returned
```

So your `toString()` method can look more or less like

```
public String toString() {
    return "account number: " + accountNumber + ", balance " + accountBalance;
}
```